# Show layout boundary without setting

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How to show layout boundary without setting it up in the Developer Options?

Usually it can shown by enabling the **Setting** > **Developer Options** > **Show layout boundaries** setting.

I'd like to switch it without such troublesome process. If it could be enabled/disabled with a simple application or even a Java code that could do it from within my application, it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution.

This tool works fine. Please install groovy before trying it.

https://github.com/dhelleberg/android-scripts